# Inline KVO of a Property in another view controller

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, swift4

I have a vc with a dynamic var "value" and i need to know when it's changed in a closure in the calling cv.

target vc:

```
@objc dynamic var value: String = ""
```

source:

```
if let vc: TagButtonPopupViewController = sb.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("TagPopupViewController")) as? TagButtonPopupViewController {
        // configure vc
        vc.value = sender.title

        // observe
        _ = vc.observe(\.value) { (tbvc, change) in
            print("new string")
        }

        // present popup
        presentViewController(vc, asPopoverRelativeTo: sender.bounds, of: sender, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.maxY, behavior: NSPopover.Behavior.transient)
    }
```

but "observe" is never called. 
Any Ideas how to get notified in a closure whenever "value" has changed in Swift4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observer is destroyed because there is no reference
to it after the other view controller has been presented.
You have to store it

```
observer = vc.observe(\.value) { ... }
```

where `observer` is a property of the calling view controller.

A self-contained command-line project example: This prints "new string" as expected:

```
class A: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var value: String = ""
}

let a = A()
let observer = a.observe(\.value) { (_, _) in print("new string") } // (*)
a.value = "Hello world"
```

But nothing is printed if `(*)` is replaced by

```
_ = a.observe(\.value) { (_, _) in print("new string") }
```

Comment: I tried this, but did'n get any results. When i change vc.value from the parent vc it will be triggered, but not if value is changed from within the vc itself. Thats strange.

Comment: `let m = {print ("xyz")};

let x = m();

let _ = m()`

The last 2 statements, both print xyz. So I'm still wondering why using `_` won't work. Or is that it works, but only for a single execution and after that it's just gone!?

Comment: @Honey: You are *calling* the closure `m` in both cases, that different from above examples. In `_ = a.observe(\.value) {  ... }`, the call returns an observer, which is then discarded and destroyed.

Comment: So we have classes, enums, structs, closures, you are saying we have something else name *observer* which is none of them? ok got it.

Comment: @Honey: That is *not* what I meant. The observer is an instance of some class. – In `a.observe(\.value) { ... }` the closure is not executed immediately, it is stored by the observer, in order to be called when the observed value changes. But since the observer is discarded immediately, the closure is never executed.

Comment: oh I see. Thank you for the correction. Would it be correct to say anything that needs to be observe, needs to be stored?

Comment: @Honey: That is to vague for me to answer.

Comment: @Martin R: what does the backslash in a.observe(\.value) do? I've not noticed this syntax in swift before.

Comment: @lozflan: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0161-key-paths.md.