# swift4 KVO not working

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing, swift4

Im using new kvo in swift4 and it works only if value of class changed outside.

```
@objcMembers class BaseGameLogic: NSObject {
    var timer: Timer!
    dynamic var time = 10

    override init() {
        super.init()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(decreaseTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func decreaseTime() {
        self.time -= 1
         print("in game logic time: \(time)")
         if time == 0 {
             timer.invalidate()
         }
    }
}
```

And in other class it looks like that:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    var gameLogic = BaseGameLogic()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let kvo = gameLogic.observe(\.time, options: [.new]) { object, value in
            print(value)
        }
    }
}
```

And i have no output on console!
But when i add after `kvo` the following line of code:

```
gameLogic.time = 20
```

I get output to console that informs that new value (20) comes and that's it.

Comment: You're not persisting the returned `NSKeyValueObservation`, so your observer will be removed at the end of `viewDidLoad()`. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/45265586/2976878

Comment: @Hamish thanks, you're right!